# JFreeChart: Display Only some point in Horizontal axis?

Tags: java, graph, jfreechart

I'm using JFreeChart Java to generate charts.

My code is something like this.

```
DefaultCategoryDataset line_chart_dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();

     line_chart_dataset.addValue(15, "TVA collectée", "1950");
     line_chart_dataset.addValue(30, "TVA collectée", "1955");
     line_chart_dataset.addValue(60, "TVA collectée", "1960");
     line_chart_dataset.addValue(120, "TVA collectée", "1965");
     line_chart_dataset.addValue(240, "TVA collectée", "1970");
     line_chart_dataset.addValue(260, "TVA collectée", "1975");
     line_chart_dataset.addValue(10, "TVA collectée", "1980");
     line_chart_dataset.addValue(260, "TVA collectée", "1982");
     line_chart_dataset.addValue(10, "TVA collectée", "1984");
     line_chart_dataset.addValue(80, "TVA collectée", "1985");
     line_chart_dataset.addValue(120, "TVA collectée", "1990");
     line_chart_dataset.addValue(240, "TVA collectée", "1995");
     line_chart_dataset.addValue(70, "TVA collectée", "2000");
     line_chart_dataset.addValue(30, "TVA collectée", "2005");
     line_chart_dataset.addValue(60, "TVA collectée", "2010");
     line_chart_dataset.addValue(300, "TVA collectée", "2015");
     line_chart_dataset.addValue(240, "TVA collectée", "2020");

     /* Step -2:Define the JFreeChart object to create line chart */
     JFreeChart lineChartObject=ChartFactory.createLineChart("Suivi des de TVA collectée et déductible","","",line_chart_dataset,PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,true,true,false);                

     /* Step -3 : Write line chart to a file */               
      int width=640; /* Width of the image */
      int height=480; /* Height of the image */                
      File lineChart=new File("line_Chart_example.png");              
      try {
        ChartUtilities.saveChartAsPNG(lineChart,lineChartObject,width,height);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

In the Horizontal axis, I want to display only some years 
for example: 1950 1960 1970 1980 1990 2000 2010 2020.

How Can I do this with JFreeChart. Can SomeOne Guides me Please?